# Where was Hagrid when Bellatrix destroyed his house?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

In the sixth Harry Potter movie, at the end when Bellatrix sets Hagrid's house on fire, where was he at the time? Also, where did he live from then on?

Answer (score 2):

> Another flash, shouts, retaliatory jets of light, and Harry
>   understood:
>   Hagrid had emerged from his cabin and was trying to stop the Death
>   Eaters
>   escaping, and though every breath seemed to shred his lungs and the
>   stitch in  his chest was like fire, Harry sped up as an unbidden voice in his
>   head said:
>   not Hagrid. . . not Hagrid too . . .

For second part There are many competent wizards beside Dumbledore who could fix his house or make him a new one.

Answer (score 2):

## Hagrid had recently come out of his house  - at least in the book.

Hagrid had been in his house to begin with, but came out to attempt to help fight the Death Eaters who had invaded Hogwarts.

> “Another flash, shouts, retaliatory jets of light, and Harry understood: Hagrid had emerged from his cabin and was trying to stop the Death Eaters escaping, and though every breath seemed to shred his lungs and the stitch in his chest was like fire, Harry sped up as an unbidden voice in his head said: not Hagrid … not Hagrid too …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 28 (Flight of the Prince)*</sup></sub>

Hagrid was outside his house when it was lit on fire, but his dog Fang was still inside.

> “But Snape parried the curse, knocking Harry backwards off his feet before he could complete it; Harry rolled over and scrambled back up again as the huge Death Eater behind him yelled, ‘Incendio!’; Harry heard an explosive bang and a dancing orange light spilled over all of them: Hagrid’s house was on fire.
>
> ‘Fang’s in there, yeh evil –!’ Hagrid bellowed.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 28 (Flight of the Prince)*</sup></sub>

He goes back inside after it’s set on fire to retrieve Fang, and both of them escape the fire unharmed.

> “Hagrid,’ muttered Harry, still dazed, looking around. ‘HAGRID?’
>
> He stumbled towards the burning house as an enormous figure emerged from out of the flames carrying Fang on his back. With a cry of thankfulness, Harry sank to his knees; he was shaking in every limb, his body ached all over and his breath came in painful stabs.
>
> ‘Yeh all righ’, Harry? Yeh all righ’? Speak ter me, Harry …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 28 (Flight of the Prince)*</sup></sub>

*It should be noted that in the book, the Death Eater who set Hagrid’s house on fire was Thorfinn Rowle, since Harry mentioned when he saw Rowle that he was one of the Death Eaters there when Dumbledore died in the book, and he’s the only Death Eater who was there described as being blond and very large.*

## After that, he presumably stayed at Hogwarts, possibly in his hut.

Hagrid volunteers to stay at Hogwarts after Dumbledore’s death.

> “Well, I’m stayin’,’ said Hagrid, fat tears still leaking out of the corners of his eyes and trickling down into his tangled beard. ‘It’s me home, it’s bin me home since I was thirteen. An’ if there’s kids who wan’ me ter teach ’em, I’ll do it. But … I dunno … Hogwarts without Dumbledore …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 29 (The Phoenix Lament)*</sup></sub>

When he talks to Harry, he mentioned taking care of freshly born unicorns, meaning he most likely retained his old job.

> “Ar, not bad. Bin busy, we got some newborn unicorns, I’ll show yeh when yeh get back –’ Harry avoided Ron and Hermione’s gaze as Hagrid rummaged in his pocket.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 7 (The Will of Albus Dumbledore)*</sup></sub>

The portrait of Phineas Nigellus Black also says Ginny, Luna, and Neville were sent into the Forbidden Forest to help Hagrid as a punishment.

> “Professor Snape sent them into the Forbidden Forest, to do some work for the oaf, Hagrid.’
>
> ‘Hagrid’s not an oaf!’ said Hermione shrilly.
>
> ‘And Snape might’ve thought that was a punishment,’ said Harry, ‘but Ginny, Neville and Luna probably had a good laugh with Hagrid. The Forbidden Forest … they’ve faced plenty worse than the Forbidden Forest, big deal!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 15 (The Goblin’s Revenge)*</sup></sub>

## He does leave at one point, but not because of the fire.

Hagrid narrowly escaped arrest at one point. The arrest was on the grounds of Hogwarts, and because of something that happened in his house. Since his house is referred to as separate from Hogwarts Castle itself, he presumably doesn’t live somewhere in the building.

> “We have also heard within the last few hours that Rubeus Hagrid –’ all three of them gasped, and so nearly missed the rest of the sentence ‘– well-known gamekeeper at Hogwarts School, has narrowly escaped arrest within the grounds of Hogwarts, where he is rumoured to have hosted a “Support Harry Potter” party in his house.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 22 (The Deathly Hallows)*</sup></sub>

After that, however, he does leave his house to go into hiding. He had stayed at Hogwarts teaching until that point.

> “Get right out of Hogsmeade, up into the mountains, and you’ll be able to Disapparate there. Might see Hagrid. He’s been hiding in a cave up there with Grawp ever since they tried to arrest him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 28 (The Missing Mirror)*</sup></sub>